# How to load Windows Phone 8 Panorama Item conditionally (Not load All Items)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I use data binding to create a panorama page.
When I go to this page, it will show all of items I add in the MainViewModel.cs.
Is it possible to just show specific items(likes item2~item4)on this panorama page.
Because I would like to create many different pages using the same ViewModel(but different several items).

Answer (score 0):

You implement two lists in your ViewModel one public which you bind your panorama to and one private which contains all the pages.

```
public class MainViewModel
{    
    public ObservableCollection<String> ItemsDisplayed; 
    private List<String> _fullList;
    public void UpdateItemsDisplayed()
    {
        if(someCriteria)
             ItemsDisplayed.Add(_fullList[1]);
    }
}
```